# int argc, const char * argv[] , why we give these input to main

Tags: command-line, arguments, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

Why we give these arguments to main ,searched a lot but couldn't find an answer to clear this doubt.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`argc` represents the number of arguments passed to the main function.

`argv[]` represents the arguments passed which are separated by space.

Eg:-

> $ ./a.out First Second Third

Program Name Is: ./a.out [argv[0]]

Number Of Arguments Passed: 4 [argc value]

----Following Are The Command Line Arguments Passed----

argv[0]: ./a.out

argv[1]: First

argv[2]: Second

argv[3]: Third

[Refer here for more information](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/)